# Acionar evento pelo nome

Tags: javascript, javascript-eventos

eu recebo por uma função o nome do evento e o elemento que deve acionar esse evento ex:

```
callEvent('click', 'btnEvent')
```

dentro dessa função eu gostaria de retornar o elemento e acionar o evento passado

retornar :

```
var elem = document.getElementById('btnEvent');
```

e depois acionar o evento mas não sei como acionar o evento sendo que eu só tenho o nome dele em uma string não gostaria de ter que fazer um if para cada evento existente;

existe algo como

`elemento.peformEvent('evento');`

Comment: Quantos tipos diferentes de eventos tens? Acionar eventos em JavaScript não é muito simples. Têm de ser eventos do DOM ou podem ser eventos internos? Podes explicar porque queres deferir os eventos dessa maneira?

Comment: seriam eventos do dom, click, keypress, blur

Comment: Podes explicar porque queres deferir os eventos? Queres criar eventos ou o código é para correr quando o utilizador disparar esses eventos?

Comment: Tenho um elemento que recebe dois data-atributes em um data- vem o evento que ele vai acionar e no outro data- qual elemento aciona (isso no keypress deste elemento que contem os data)

entao fica <input type="text" data-event="click" dataElement='btnAcionar" id="txtAlgumaCoisa">

entao no keyypress no txtAlgumaCoisa o js pega qual é o elemento e o evento que vaio ser disparado.